# What does the sum $0(1/4)+1(3/4)(1/4)+2(3/4)^2(1/4)+3(3/4)^3(1/4)+⋯$ equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What does the sum $$0(1/4)+1(3/4)(1/4)+2(3/4)^2(1/4)+3(3/4)^3(1/4)+⋯$$ equal?

---

I simplified it to $$3/16(1+2(3/4)+3(3/4)^2+ \cdots)$$ but now I'm stuck.  Solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Geometric series

Comment: Compute $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over 4} x^k$ and differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ S = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n 3^n}{4^{n+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n 3^n}{4^{n+1}} $$
and consider that
$$ 4S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n 3^n}{4^n} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+1)3^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}} = 3\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+1) 3^n}{4^{n+1}}=3S+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}} $$
so that
$$S = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}} = \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{1-\frac{3}{4}}=\color{red}{3}.$$